# background opacity less mixin possible?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible in Less to create a mixin that can target the backgroubd opacity of an element that already has its background colour set by an existing rule?

E.g

```
div {
    background-colour: red;
}

.opacity {
    background-color: fade(@existing-bg, 50%)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then not in the sense that you are trying to do - @existing-bg would need to be able to assess the current BG colour at RUNTIME but essentially, we use LESS at compile time. The answer would be to put the colour (red) in a variable and supply the same variable in both places.

```
@existing: #ff0000;
div {
     background-colour: @existing;
}

.opacity {
     background-color: fade(@existing, 50%)
}
```

Comment: +1 for a thorough explanation of why it's not possible.